# Can one repeat a siyum?

Tags: talmud-gemara, siyum

A few summer camps have a small dining room that can't fit all the campers and counselors for a meal at one time. Therefore, the camp schedules two meal shifts.

During the Nine Days, the camp schedules a *siyum* for, say, lunch so that they can eat meat. Can the person who makes the siyum for the first shift repeat the *siyum* on the same *masechta* for the second shift? Or is a *siyum* a "one shot deal"? Let's say no one else is available to make a *siyum* on a different (or same) *masechta* for the 2nd shift. Does that change anything?

Comment: if you finish a set of mishnayos for a mourner to say kaddish can you repeat kaddish without repeating the mishnayos?

Comment: @Dude The Kaddish said after a siyum is said by the person who lead the siyum, who may not necessarily be a mourner.

Comment: I never said that the person saying kaddish for a siyum was a mourner. It seems like there is a similarity in finishing mishnayos so a mourner can saying kaddish and saying kaddish as part of a siyum. That being the case my question was meant to imply it doesn't seem like you can say kaddish again when that has already happened without learning that mesechta again just like I don't think kaddish could be said twice in a row after a set of mishnayos are said with repeating the mishanyos. Perhaps your real question is if those who didn't hear the siyum may partake in the seduas mitzvah?

Comment: @Dude I know the answer regarding joining a seudah if you didn't hear the siyum. In this case, it is clear that this is a separate seudah, as there are 2 separate dining room shifts. I see your Q about saying Kaddish twice. I'm not sure if that's a factor. Even if it is, perhaps, someone else who hears the siyum can say Kaddish.